# Generator of translations in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, second-quantization

In first quantization I've easily shown that the momentum operator is the generator of translations. I simply used the Baker-Hausdorff relation and the definition of Taylor series to show that.

But now in second quantization, my total momentum operator is defined as $T=\sum_{k\sigma} \vec{k}c^\dagger_{k\sigma}c_{k\sigma}$ and I want to show, once again, that it is the generator of space translations, i.e, I want to show that:

$$e^{iTr_0}\psi(r)e^{-iTr_0}=\psi(r-r_0)$$

where $\psi_{\sigma}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L^d}}\sum_{k\sigma}e^{ikr}c_{k\sigma}$ is the field operator. I've been around this already for some time and can't manage to prove the relation above.

Comment: Show your work!

Comment: Hint: $e^{i\alpha c^{\dagger}_k c_k}c_{k} e^{-i\alpha c^{\dagger}_k c_k} = e^{-i\alpha }c_k$